# Echo Output on the Same line

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying get a output printed on a same line using echo command in bash script. Echo Command is given inside a loop, everytime the loop runs, executes a echo command. But normally, echo will take a new line everytime it executes, but I want the output to be on the same line everytime it executes.

This is how my sample small code look:

```
 #!/bin/bash
loop=1;
while [ $loop -lt 5 ];
do
echo "-"
let loop=loop+1
done
```

I also tried with -n option of echo command, but I got no output. I replaced the stmt - echo "-" with echo -n "-".

Desired output is:
"-----"

Can some one help me on this

Comment: How is this related to powershell?

Comment: I am beginner to shell. 'Powershell' also appeared as a suggestions to the tags. I don really know the difference between the shell and powershell.

Comment: You can always hover over the tags and it will give you a description. I removed the tag and added [tag:bash] so the right people will find your question.

Comment: I just tried your script with replacing `echo "-"` with `echo -n "-"` and it seemed to work for me

Comment: `echo -n` and `printf` should both work, i.e. `for ((i=1; i<5; i++)); do printf '-'; done`

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said you tried

```
echo -n "-"
```

which should have worked. In fact, I suspect that it did.

The problem may be that you don't have a newline at the very end of your output. With the change to

```
echo -n "-"
```

your script should print 5 `-` characters with no newline. The output may have been clobbered by the shell prompt printed after your script finishes.

As a quick test, try adding

```
sleep 5
```

to the end of your script and see if the `-----` appears. After 5 seconds, see what happens when your next shell prompt is printed.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
loop=1;
while [ $loop -lt 5 ]
do
    echo -n "-"
    let loop=loop+1
done
echo ""
```

The final `echo ""` prints just a newline.

Some other things to note:

Indentation is important, especially for larger and more complex scripts.  It shows the structure of your code at a glance and makes it much easier to read.

In the code in your question, you have a space in front of the `#!/bin/bash`.  The `#!` is recognized only at the very beginning of the line. Without a valid `#!` line, your script will be executed by `/bin/sh`, not by `/bin/bash`. It probably doesn't matter in this case, since you're not using any bash-specific features. It may have been an error introduced when you posted the question, but be sure to check your actual script and remove the space if it's there.

The `echo` command exists in a number of different versions. It's built into most shells, and also available as a separate executable `/bin/echo`. The different versions can have subtly different behavior in which options they recognize and the syntax of special characters. Support for the `-n` option to print a line with no terminating newline is probably *almost* universal.

The `printf` command (similar to C's `printf()` function) also exists in multiple implementations, but its behavior is much more consistent. It's safer to use `printf` rather than `echo` if you're doing anything more than printing a simple one-line message. Again, it probably won't matter in this case, but it's a good thing to keep in mind.

Comment: Indentation matters, but newlines do as well, your "; ... do" only requires the ";" when the "do" is on on the same line as the "while", otherwise the newline is sufficient.  The "echo" at the end normally shouldn't need a '""', unless you're trying to account for the many different slightly-incompatible implementations of "echo", in which case "echo -n" isn't reliable either, only "echo ..stuff.. | tr -d '\012'" if real resilience cross-unix-platform is the objective.  Of course, he did say "bash", so you probably don't need to drop to using "tr".

Comment: @AlexNorth-Keys: You're right about the `;`, and I've removed it, but it seems to be harmless. Yes, the purpose of using `echo ""` rather than `echo` was to cater to different implementations of `echo`; I think I've used versions where `echo` with no arguments would print nothing. I *think* that `echo -n` is more portable than `echo` with no arguments, but if you're that concerned with portability you should probably use `printf` anyway (unless you're on a *really* old system that doesn't have it). I don't know how portable `tr`'s handling of the `'\012'` syntax is.

Comment: The tr has worked everywhere I've tried it.  echo can't be relied on for much of anything in the broader unix realm - with no args it might output nothing, or a newline, or a space(!) and a newline. Some always append a space after the last arg, some don't.  I'd be cautious about anything with a dash in front, yet the "--" syntax to indicate no more options can't be relied on.  Even the built-in echo in some shells can't be relied on... Sun's used to change depending on your search path, guessing whether one preferred SysV or BSD semantics therefrom.  Heh.:-)

Comment: Thanks both. @KeithThompson: Can you eloborate the purpose echo "" at the end? With out the stmt, the script returs no output. But using the stmt I can see the desired output. What difference it makes?

Comment: @user3624000: The `echo ""` prints a newline character. Usually (but not always) the output of a program should consist of complete lines, meaning there should be a newline at the very end. Are you *certain* it doesn't produce any output at all without the `echo ""`? Did you try adding the `sleep 5` as I suggested?

Comment: Without `echo ""` and `Sleep 5`, script returs no output (no errors also). Using `Sleep 5` at the end of the script (after `done`), gives output but script seems to have not ended, It has not returned to command line (I used Ctrl+c to end the script). Using `echo ""` is perfect, gives proper output

Comment: Is the space in front of `#!/bin/bash` actually there in your script? What does `echo "$PS1"` print? Did you try `Sleep 5` or `sleep 5` (command names are case-sensitive)? If you try the script without either `echo ""` or `sleep 5`, what happens if you type `./name-of-script ; echo ""` ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `echo` for informational messages only and use `printf` for everything else, since it is a much more powerful, flexible and *reliable* tool.  The sequence of statements

```
printf '-'
printf '-'
printf '-'
printf '-'
printf '-'
```

actually produce the output `-----`.

Comment: Yes, but there's no reason that should behave differently than `echo -n "-"`.

Comment: The form `echo -n` is not portable and use of the echo command is discouraged: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html

Comment: Yes, but the OP is using bash (assuming the space in front of the `#!` isn't there in the actual script), and `echo -n` works in bash. Even if the `#!` is incorrect, as I mentioned in my answer, it's unlikely that the OP is using an implementation where `-n` doesn't work. If he were, it would print a literal `-n`, which the OP doesn't report. You raise a valid point about using `printf` rather than `echo`, but it's unlikely to be the answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Only reliable if on a recent Unix system, like Linux, of course.  Old Unixen don't have printf as a command.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead of your current echo statement:

> echo -e "-/c"

The -e option allows echo to take delimiters, and the /c stops output (in this case the trailing newline that you don't want).

Comment: The `-e` option to `echo` is probably less portable than `-n`.

Comment: As you pointed out, OP is using bash, which means it should work, though it does have portability issues. However, that might not even be a concern of OP, and the /c solution would work swimmingly.